# Shimano cassette replacement compatibility

Tags: shimano, cassette, compatibility

I have a Marin bike with Shimano Deore gears. I think I need to replace the cassette, which is a 9-speed with the Shimano code CS-HG61-9. That cassette seems to be discontinued, as I cannot find it in stock anywhere. Will I be able to replace it with another Shimano 9-speed cassette? Are there any 'gotchas' to beware of?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The [CS-HG400-9](https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/component/alivio-t4000/CS-HG400-9.html) from Shimano would be a suitable replacement.

Your CS-HG61-9 comes in different sprocket configurations (11-32, 11-34, 11-28 and 12-36). The first number is the number of teeth of the smallest sprocket while the second number is for the largest sprocket. If you want your gears to have the same ratio, consider getting a new cassette with an equivalent sprocket configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Any other 9-speed cassette will do (whatever the brand), provided that the size of the different cogs (the extremes in fact) are compatible with the derailleur.

Comment: Thank you! How might I check the compatibility condition you mentioned?

Comment: @MarcoOcram It depends on the model of the derailleur (it's written on it, but not obvious, the format for Shimano is RD-Mxxx), then you can find the specs online easily. Or you can look at the cassette, the size also usually written on the sprockets - format: 34T, and take the same one.